# Open iframe from menu and change url

Tags: jquery, url, iframe, menu

The html part：

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="Offselect" href="aa.html">A</a>
            <ul>
                <a id="bb" class="Onselect" href="bb.html">B</a>
                <a id="cc" class="Offselect" href="cc.html">C</a>
                <a id="dd" class="Offselect" href="dd.html">D</a>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li><a id="ee" class="Offselect" href="ee.html">E</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

The jQuery part：

```
 $(function() {
        var pageurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        $('#menu a').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('href') == pageurl || $(this).attr('href') == ''){
                $(this).addClass('Onselect');
            }
            else{
                $(this).addClass('Offselect');
            }
        });
    });

$(function() {
    var $content = $('#iframe');
    $('#menu a')
        .click(function() {
            $content.attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
            return false;
        });
});
```

My question is to change url when menu item opened, how to update the url address to match the iframe url？Can anybody help？thx！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class assignment script is executed only once when the main page is loaded, not when the iframe is changed.

So one possible solution is to add the class change logic to the click handler also so that it will remove the `onSelect` class from the previous element and will add the `onSelect` class to current element.

```
$(function () {
    var $content = $('#iframe');
    $('#menu a')
        .click(function () {
        $content.attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));

         $('#menu a.Onselect').removeClass('Onselect').addClass('Offselect');
         $(this).addClass('Onselect').removeClass('Offselect');

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thx for your help，the class problem just fixed，but I still can not change the url that I clicked.

Comment: @SC.Peng what do you mean by `but I still can not change the url that I clicked` - do you mean the iframe is not getting updated

Comment: I clicked `bb.html` or `cc.html`...etc，iframe updated to bb.html or cc.html，but url still look like `http://example.com/aa.html`，it didn't update to `http://example.com/bb.html` or `http://example.com/cc.html`

Comment: Try to add `window.history.pushState({},"", '/' + $(this).attr('href'));` just before teh return stmt